# Android Can't retain fragments that are nested in other fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

there is sth wrong with my Application,I try to **add three Fragments in another Fragment**,then the Eclipse show this:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't retain fragements that are nested in other fragments

this is my code in the childFragments

```
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.shop_fragment_container, shopTopOneFragment)
            .add(R.id.shop_fragment_container, shopTopTwoFragment)
            .add(R.id.shop_fragment_container, shopTopThreeFragment)
            .hide(shopTopTwoFragment).hide(shopTopThreeFragment)
            .show(shopTopOneFragment).commit();
```

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Can't retain fragements that are nested in other fragments

This is a limitation of nested `Fragments`. I'm guessing one or more of your child `Fragments` have `setRetainInstance(true)` somewhere in their code. You need to remove that to prevent the error.

EDIT: On further reading it seems if the parent `Fragment` is calling `setRetainInstance(true)` then it will cause the same exception due to the fact that attempting to retain the parent instance also attempts to retain the child `Fragments`.

Comment: I checked my code,but can't find **the setRetainInstance(true)**.

Comment: @DomonLee : Are you calling `setRetainInstance(true)` in your parent `Fragment`?

Comment: I checked my code again,and find this in my parent Fragment.Then I remove that,everything is ok!! Thanks~

Comment: @DomonLee : Glad to help. I did some further reading which suggested the cause was the parent `Fragment`. I've edited my answer.

Comment: It helps for solving issue occurs in Eclipse project. Thank you. By the way, the same code "setRetainInstance(true") in Android Studio runs properly.